# Why there is no `expectAsync3` in dart's unittest?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I see there are `expectAsync0`, `expectAsync1`, `expectAsync2` provided by dart's unittest library, but no `expectAsync3`, `expectAsync4`, ...

What if I want to test a function which has 3 parameters?

```dart
myadd(int x, int y, int z) { return x+y+z; }
```

I expect to write:

```dart
var fun = expectAsync3(myadd);
```

But I can't find such a method.

Answer (score 2):

As Günter Zöchbauer said: there wasn't probably any demand for it.

In the meantime you can work around it:

```dart
var done = expectAsync0(() {});
var fun = (x, y, z) { done(); return myadd(x, y, z); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because nobody filed a feature request for it.

AFAIR there are plans to extend reflections capability to call functions with an unlimited number of parameters. These `xxxX()` methods are a workaround until this feature has landed.

**EDIT**

found it
The limitation seems to come from `typedef` not from reflection.

- [Remove N from all expectAsyncN](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9780)
- [relax function subtyping](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2706)
- [unittest: Remove expectAsync/expectAsyncUntil](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14722) (seems to be a workaround)